# Durandal and JavaScript Strict Mode. How to get the instance to Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

Durandal uses Knockout therefor the Knockout script needs to be loaded before Durandal. When using strict mode in JavaScript on my ViewModel the "ko" variable does not exist and gives me an error. I think I need to be able to load Knockout as a module but doing this will load knockout twice and then my bindings get messy. I can't seem to get my hands on the instance of Knockout that Durandal uses.

How would I go around doing this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here!

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is “you can't”.

Durandal uses Knockout as a global object as you say to make it a bit easier when developing (same with jQuery). This would require a change to Durandal to always load Knockout and jQuery as modules.